# Why sudo -i needs an absolute path to run a script?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

```
[USER@HOST ~]$ cat tmp.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script run successfully."
```

```
[USER@HOST ~]$ sudo ./tmp.sh
Script run successfully.

[USER@HOST ~]$ sudo -i ./tmp.sh
-bash: ./tmp.sh: No such file or directory

[USER@HOST ~]$ sudo -i /home/USER/tmp.sh
Script run successfully.
```

When running a bash script with sudo, `sudo -i` seems to require an absolute path.

Why is this so, and how can I make `sudo -i` refer the same path as `sudo`?

---

EDITED

`sudo -i ~/tmp.sh` works well.

It seems that `sudo -i` doesn't get `.` location.

Comment: `sudo -i` tries to change to the user's home directory. Try `sudo -i pwd`.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo -i seems to require an absolute path.

No it does not. You can do relative to the new location, ie. to `/root`:

```
sudo -i ../home/USER/tmp.sh
```

should also work.

> Why is this so

Because you passed `-i` to `sudo` and from `man sudo` it does:

> ```
>  -i, --login
> ```
>
> [...] sudo attempts to change to that user's  home directory before running the shell. [...]

> how can I make sudo -i refer the same path as sudo?

Change root home directory to current directory (ugh!).

Do not pass `-i` option. Well... you can run `bash -l` yourself.

[Patch `sudo`](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/24e1774ce322dad53c5f7893b8eafe9ac1f57abc/plugins/sudoers/env.c#L874) and change the behavior of `-i` option.

Note that passing `-E` and `-i` to `sudo` is not allowed together.

> sudo -i ~/tmp.sh works well.

Yes, because `~` is expanded **before** sudo is run. It's the same as running sudo with an absolute path.

```
$ set -x
$ sudo -i ~/tmp.sh
+ sudo -i /home/kamil/tmp.sh
-bash: line 1: /home/kamil/tmp.sh: No such file or directory
```